# Would/Do you mind...? vs. Will you mind...?

Tags: would

Why is it that you can say "Would/Do you mind...?" but not exactly "Will you mind...?"?

For example:

> (1) Would you mind my smoking here?
>
> (2) Do you mind my smoking here?
>
> (3) Will you mind my smoking here? (??)

Is it simply a matter of usage?

Or is there some logical explanation for that?

Specifically, the question might boil down to answering the following questions:

Is (1) a "polite" form of (3) and somehow has (3) lost its usage?

Alternatively, is (1) a hypothetical/unreal version of (2), as in "If you were in the hypothetical situation, would you mind my smoking here?"

Answer (score 1):

The third example means something different.

> Will you mind my smoking here?

implies that you intend to smoke despite any objections, but that you may be willing to work out some sort of compromise.

Comment: Would you say the same thing for "Will you mind if I smoke here?"?

Comment: Not as much. The *if* makes it more conditional, softening it somewhat.

Comment: So maybe it's not "Will you" itself that implies what you say implies, is it?

Comment: No, it definitely has that overtone. It doesn't *have* to mean that, just as "I'm going to shoot you in the head" doesn't *have* to mean what it says. But if you don't mean those words, and use them anyway, don't be surprised if your meaning is misconstrued.

Answer (score 1):

1. Would you mind IF I smoked here? More about permission, is it allowed
2. Do you mind IF I smoke here? More about personal choice, does it bother you personally
3. Will you mind IF I smoke here? Looking for attention/support, if you want to destroy your lungs go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that (1) is a more polite version of (3) but your usage of "my smoking" instead of saying something like "me smoking" makes each question all polite.

I think that (3) sounds more so... impolite because of the fact that it's almost saying like you're almost intimidating someone by using a future tense verb.

Comment: I'm not sure how 'will you' in and of itself could sound 'impolite' much less 'intimidating' simply because it's 'a future tense verb.' For example, would a lady feel slighted/intimidated when asked "Will you marry me?"?